# SafeMath library vs SafeMath contract on the inheritance chain

Tags: solidity, erc-20, library, openzeppelin

guys, I am developing ERC-20 token and I am wondering why SafeMath is used as as library in the [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20) implementation? Will not it be more optimal if we supply it as a base contract on the inheritance chain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SafeMath's functions are all declared as `internal`. That means that the library doesn't actually have to be deployed, as the functions are 'inlined' by the compiler: their code is just copied from the library code to the calling function.

An inheritance relationship like `contract A is B`, `A` is a `B`. In case of `SafeMath`, that does not hold if I just want to use `SafeMath`'s functionality in another contract.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as far as gas cost is concerned, it is more optimal when used as a library, since you do not make external function calls (the library functions reside within your contract).

In addition, SafeMath is a "library by nature", i.e., it supplies a specific yet general kind of functionality, so it makes a lot more sense to declare it as a library.

The only down side of it being a library, is that if you ever want to make changes in it, then you will have to redeploy the entire contract, since it does not contain a reference to a SafeMath contract, for which you can add a setter function in advance.